# Can a truncated crypto hash of a truncated crypto hash help harden a resource against attacks?

Tags: cryptography, hash

In a project of mine, I have two fields which I need to use for storing a cryptographic signature (hash) of a file, but I can only use 112 bits in total, spread as 16+12 hex chars in those two fields.

Since I cannot store a full SHA256, I intend to use a truncated SHA256 value. Which of the following scenarios would be cryptographically "safest" given the constraint of 28 hex chars?

**a)** truncate a full SHA256 to 28 hex chars and store the result as a concatenated value in those two fields (16+12).

**b)** truncate a full SHA256 to 16 chars and store the result in the longer field, **PLUS**
generate another SHA256 of the original full SHA256 hash, truncate it to 12 chars and store it in the shorter field.

**c)** truncate a full SHA256 to 16 chars and store the result in the longer field
**PLUS** generate another crypto hash for the resource (BLAKE2, RIPEMD256, whatever solid), truncate it to 12 chars and store it in the shorter field.

Thanks very much for responses.

Comment: I would also evaluate a truncated MD5 (112/128 bits) or truncated SHA-1 (112/160). They might actually still have better properties than a truncated sha256. Also, MD6 supports a variable length between 0 and 512 bits, so it'd be worth checking..

Comment: 112 bits is too small to be secure against the collision attack. However, finding a secondary image still cost 2^112. Options will only make it a little harder.

Comment: Can you store the output of the hash as [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)? That would allow you to store 168 bits of the hash instead of 112, which is more or less resistant to a collision attack (at least against non-state sponsored adversaries).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, this scheme isn't especially secure, since, as kelalaka points out, this doesn't provide enough security with hex characters.

If you can store arbitrary binary in these fields, I would use either a SHA3-224 or a BLAKE2b-224 hash for this purpose, since it's going to be able to store the entire thing there.  SHA-224 (the SHA-2 variant) is also okay if you're certain your application doesn't need significant resistance against length-extension attacks.

If you can't store arbitrary binary, then I'd store it in Ascii85 (without the start and end markers) or base64url encoding if possible to get as many bytes as possible out of the encoded characters.  In this case, I'd use BLAKE2b because it can be truncated specifically to any number of bytes, although SHA-512/t is also a possibility.  The latter may be hard to find as a generic function in major crypto libraries, though.  You *can* use a truncated function here, but it's preferable to use a hash of exactly the right length.

I'd stick with one strong algorithm over the main data here instead of splitting it between multiple algorithms.  I don't think you gain anything with multiple algorithms, and SHA-2, SHA-3, and BLAKE2b are all thought to be robust and strong.  Ultimately, your goal is to provide as many bits as possible to hard against the canonical attacks, and there's no reason to think hashes of hashes provide any better integrity there.

I would definitely not use MD5 or SHA-1 in any new application for any purpose.  They are known to have significant weaknesses when it comes to collisions and things won't be any better when you truncate them.  In general, unless you get advice from a reputable cryptographer that you *should* use MD5 or SHA-1 in a new application, you should not.  Even if you don't need cryptographic security, another option is better.